# White Screen Appearing When using ShowDialog method Of WPF Window after Hiding

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, revit-api

I am developing an Add-in for Autodesk Revit, I have created a WPF Window using XAML and C# as shown in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjhrW.png). User of my add-in needs to switch between my Window and Revit and my window needs to maintain its state.

Being it is a modal dialog user cannot interact with Revit until my window is opened. So, in this situation I use Hide instead of close window. And when the user needs it again the add-in uses ShowDialog to display the window again.

But the problem is when I show the window again, it appears white washed (no controls are visible) as shown in image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCQfG.jpg). And as soon as I resize my window, all the controls appear back and window starts working normally.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

```
public partial class NavigationWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
...
}
```

using this code to show,

```
NavigationWindow navigationWindow = new NavigationWindow(); 
navigationWindow.ShowDialog ();
```

To Hide Window, I am using,

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke (() =>
{
    this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
});
```

Any ideas on how can this be fixed?

Comment: I've never used `ShowDialog` in a situation where the window is hidden or collapsed instead of closed.  The point of `ShowDialog` is that it blocks until the user responds, closing the dialog.  Do you actually _need_ to use `ShowDialog` for this add-in?  I recommend avoiding modal dialogs unless it's truly necessary.  It's usually enough to set the dialog's owner to the app's main window.

Comment: put `Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, (NoArgDelegate)delegate { });` after the `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke (() =>
{
    this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
});`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go with a modeless window instead. This is the proper way to keep the window up while interacting with Revit. The way to go about this is to use the `IdleEvent` or `ExternalEvent`. Here's a simple scenario with an idle event. Just switch the `window.ShowDialog()` to `window.Show()` that will make it modeless.

First you need to add an idle event queue and handler to the `IExternalApplication` so something like this:

```
public class AppCommand : IExternalApplication
{
    private static Queue<Action<UIApplication>> Tasks;
    public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
    {
        Tasks = new Queue<Action<UIApplication>>();
        application.Idling += OnIdling;

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
    private static void OnIdling(object sender, IdlingEventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (UIApplication)sender;
        lock (Tasks)
        {
            if (Tasks.Count <= 0) return;

            var task = Tasks.Dequeue();
            task(app);
        }
    }
    public static void EnqueueTask(Action<UIApplication> task)
    {
        lock (Tasks)
        {
            Tasks.Enqueue(task);
        }
    }
}
```

So, Idling event is going to fire when Revit is not doing anything. That's a perfect time to interact with Revit from another thread (UI). So when you are in a modless dialog and want to send a task to Revit, you can just use the `EnquuqTask` utility to put a task into a queue and then Revit when it's not busy will fire Idling event, dequeue the task and execute it. This guarantees that you are not executing anything outside of Revit's scope, and will let you keep the window in modeless state allowing for interaction with Revit while the window is open.

Here's how to add a task to queue from anywhere:

```
EnqueueTask(app =>
{
    //do something
    //use app object to interact with Revit
});
```